# Call exiftool from a python script?

Tags: python, exiftool

I'm looking to use exiftool to scan the EXIF tags from my photos and videos. It's a perl executable. What's the best way to inferface with this? Are there any Python libraries to do this already? Or should I directly call the executable and parse the output? (The latter seems dirty.) Thanks.

The reason I ask is this because I am currently using pyexiv2, which does not have support for videos. Perl's exiftool has very broad support for images and videos, and I'd like to use it.

Comment: You should read the docs of the suprocess module: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: I have uploaded a more complete version of the code in my answer to https://github.com/smarnach/pyexiftool.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To avoid launching a new process for each image, you should start `exiftool` using the [`-stay_open`](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#item__2dstay_open_flag) flag.  You can then send commands to the process via stdin, and read the output on stdout.  ExifTool supports JSON output, which is probably the best option for reading the metadata.

Here's a simple class that launches an `exiftool` process and features an `execute()` method to send commands to that process.  I also included `get_metadata()` to read the metadata in JSON format:

```
import subprocess
import os
import json

class ExifTool(object):

    sentinel = "{ready}\n"

    def __init__(self, executable="/usr/bin/exiftool"):
        self.executable = executable

    def __enter__(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(
            [self.executable, "-stay_open", "True",  "-@", "-"],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        return self

    def  __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.process.stdin.write("-stay_open\nFalse\n")
        self.process.stdin.flush()

    def execute(self, *args):
        args = args + ("-execute\n",)
        self.process.stdin.write(str.join("\n", args))
        self.process.stdin.flush()
        output = ""
        fd = self.process.stdout.fileno()
        while not output.endswith(self.sentinel):
            output += os.read(fd, 4096)
        return output[:-len(self.sentinel)]

    def get_metadata(self, *filenames):
        return json.loads(self.execute("-G", "-j", "-n", *filenames))
```

This class is written as a context manager to ensure the process is exited if you are done. You can use it as

```
with ExifTool() as e:
    metadata = e.get_metadata(*filenames)
```

EDIT for python 3:
To get this to work in python 3 two small changes are needed. The first is an additional argument to `subprocess.Popen`:

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(
         [self.executable, "-stay_open", "True",  "-@", "-"],
         universal_newlines=True,
         stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The second is that you have to decode the byte series returned by `os.read()`:

```
output += os.read(fd, 4096).decode('utf-8')
```

EDIT for Windows: To get this working on Windows, the `sentinel` need to be changed into `"{ready}\r\n"`, i.e.

```
sentinel = "{ready}\r\n"
```

Otherwise the program will hang because the while loop inside execute() won't stop

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. How would I pass commands to exiftool so that the executable "stays open?" If I put the executable in a function called parseImage(), wouldn't it re-open every time the function gets called?

Comment: @ensnare: I included a bit of code.  I will improve the code in a few mintes.

Comment: Why the low-level `os` calls?

Comment: @Taymon: It was the only way I got this working without stopping on the first EOF.  Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Testing this now, but I keep getting the error "AttributeError: 'ExifTool' object has no attribute 'process'" -- any idea what this could mean? Thanks.

Comment: @ensnare: It means you didn't use `ExifTool` as shown in the example.  The `process` attribute is only created when the context is entered.

Comment: Got it -- thanks, you are right. How can I get to use this from a class where a function scanImage() is called for each individual image?

Comment: @ensnare: This depends on the design of your program.  Use a class, a closure, or maybe even a global variable to hold the `ExifTool` instance.

Comment: How could I send a dict of filenames to the get_metadata() function?

Comment: @ensnare: Not really with the current code.  What should this be useful for?

Comment: I'm trying to get a sense of the *filenames variable. How would you supply images to this? Maybe *filenames is misleading me, and the variable should be called *file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9873/discussion-between-ensnare-and-sven-marnach)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I learned a lot and the other wraps out there do not seem to care about keeping the process open. I suggested an edit for python 3 compatibility, I hope this kind of gravedigging is ok on stackoverflow.

Comment: So embarrassing. After a whole lot of reading I got it to work myself and now I see that you already created a python3 compatible version and put it on github... - sorry.

Comment: @Gringo Yep, see my comment on the question.

Comment: Cool, might wanna make it more prominent and emphasize the PyPi package to be installed with pip for ease of use.  Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

**using this as reference ...**

```
import subprocess
import os
import json

class ExifTool(object):

    sentinel = "{ready}\n"

    def __init__(self, executable="/usr/bin/exiftool"):
        self.executable = executable

    def __enter__(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(
            [self.executable, "-stay_open", "True",  "-@", "-"],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        return self

    def  __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.process.stdin.write("-stay_open\nFalse\n")
        self.process.stdin.flush()

    def execute(self, *args):
        args = args + ("-execute\n",)
        self.process.stdin.write(str.join("\n", args))
        self.process.stdin.flush()
        output = ""
        fd = self.process.stdout.fileno()
        while not output.endswith(self.sentinel):
            output += os.read(fd, 4096)
        return output[:-len(self.sentinel)]

    def get_metadata(self, *filenames):
        return json.loads(self.execute("-G", "-j", "-n", *filenames))
```

**... return follow ERROR using Python 3.8.10 and IPYTHON;**

> " AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent
> call last)  in 
> 56
> 57 e = ExifTool()
> ---> 58 e.load_metadata_lookup('/u02/RECOVERY/')
>
> in load_metadata_lookup(self, locDir)
> 51                       '\n FILELOC     > ', FileLoc, '\n')
> 52
> ---> 53                                 self.get_metadata(FileLoc)
> 54
> 55
>
> in get_metadata(self, FileLoc)
> 38
> 39         def get_metadata(self, FileLoc):
> ---> 40                 return json.loads(self.execute("-G", "-j", "-n", FileLoc))
> 41
> 42
>
> in execute(self, *args)
> 28         def execute(self, *args):
> 29                 args = args + ("-execute\n",)
> ---> 30                 self.process.stdin.write(str.join("\n", args))
> 31                 self.process.stdin.flush()
> 32                 output = ""
>
> AttributeError: 'ExifTool' object has no attribute 'process'

...

**then with some modifications ... SUCCESS!!! ...
modified and adaptations using
[https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach]**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
#! -*- coding: utf-8-mb4 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import

import sys
import os
import subprocess
import json

headers_infos = """
.:.
.:. box33 | systems | platform |
.:. [   Renan Moura     ]
.:. [   ver.: 9.1.2-b   ]
.:.
"""

class ExifTool(object):
    sentinel = "{ready}\n"
    def __init__(self):
        self.executable         = "/usr/bin/exiftool"
        self.metadata_lookup    = {}

    def  __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.process.stdin.write("-stay_open\nFalse\n")
        self.process.stdin.flush()

    def execute(self, *args):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen([self.executable, "-stay_open", "True",  "-@", "-"],
            universal_newlines  = True                          ,
            stdin               = subprocess.PIPE               ,
            stdout              = subprocess.PIPE               ,
            stderr              = subprocess.STDOUT
        )

        args = (args + ("-execute\n",))

        self.process.stdin.write(str.join("\n", args))
        self.process.stdin.flush()

        output  = ""
        fd      = self.process.stdout.fileno()

        while not output.endswith(self.sentinel):
            output += os.read(fd, 4096).decode('utf-8')

        return output[:-len(self.sentinel)]

    def get_metadata(self, *FileLoc):
        return json.loads(self.execute("-G", "-j", "-n", *FileLoc))

    def load_metadata_lookup(self, locDir):
        self.metadata_lookup = {}
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(locDir):
            for filename in filenames:
                FileLoc=(dirname + '/' + filename)
                print(  '\n FILENAME    > ', filename,
                        '\n DIRNAMES    > ', dirnames,
                        '\n DIRNAME     > ', dirname,
                        '\n FILELOC     > ', FileLoc, '\n')

                self.metadata_lookup = self.get_metadata(FileLoc)
                print(json.dumps(self.metadata_lookup, indent=3))

e = ExifTool()
e.load_metadata_lookup('/u02/RECOVERY/')
```

**... NOTE
this code ll from "/u02/RECOVERY/" ... directory find and execute on every document found ...
hope this could help u ...**

Answer (score 0):

This still turns up in searches, but using stay open etc, is barely faster than just running up subprocess individually for each file. exiftool will handle any number of files at a time, so to process a bunch of files, and extract specific metadata fields, this goes about 8 times faster on my laptop:

```
def meta_for_batch(fieldlist, filelist):
batchup = ['exiftool', '-j'] + fieldlist + filelist
res = subprocess.run(batchup, capture_output=True)
if res.returncode != 0:
    errdata=('STDERR:\n' + res.stderr.decode() if isinstance(res.stderr, bytes) else res.stderr + 
            'STDOUT:' + res.stdout.decode() if isinstance(res.stdout, bytes) else res.stdout)
    raise ValueError(errdata)
return json.loads(res.stdout)
```

Windoze may have a problem with long lists of files, so you my need to do it using an argfile. On Linux I have run this with 600 files, and it took 11.5 seconds

For example:

```
reclist = meta_for_batch(
['-FocalLength', '-ImageHeight', '-ISO', 
'-Model', '-CameraTemperature', '-SerialNumber', 
'-ExposureTime', '-LensSerialNumber', 
'-ImageWidth', '-LensModel', '-SubSecCreateDate'],
['_23A1000.CR3', '_23A1002.CR3', '_23A1003.CR3'])
```

Use exiftool use -args to get the field names