# Python native library to read metadata from videos?

Tags: python, exiftool, pyexiv2

Is there a Python library to read metadata (camera model, time created, etc ...) from video files? The Perl equivalent is "exiftool." I checked pyexiv2, but it doesn't have video support like exiftool does. Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend using ExifTool over pyexiv2 anyway, even in Python.  ExifTool is much more complete and versatile.  See [my answer on this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10075210/279627).

Answer (score 5):

I have used hachoir-metadata succesfully: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hachoir-metadata

Answer (score 3):

I have used `PyExifTool`, a wrapper for the command line program, exif tool. You can get the library [here](http://github.com/smarnach/pyexiftool) (I think this is the result of the related question in Sven's comment).

The neat thing about PyExifTool is that it also parses the metadata into a dictionary for you.

I used it on a list of file names from os.walk.

```
import exiftool 
exif_Executable="<path to exif executable>"    

with exiftool.ExifTool(executable_=exif_Executable) as et:
        metadata = et.get_metadata_batch(fileList)
```