# how to convert "b'\\xfe\\xff\\x002\\x000\\x001\\x009'" to character in python

Tags: python, encoding, hex

I have a program, which is returning strings like : `b'\\xfe\\xff\\x000\\x008\\x00/\\x001\\x002\\x00/\\x001\\x009\\x009\\x003'`
How can I convert this to a readable string. The value of this should be `08/12/1993`
so imagine i have something like this

```
a = "b'\\xfe\\xff\\x000\\x008\\x00/\\x001\\x002\\x00/\\x001\\x009\\x009\\x003'"
print(a.convert())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence `\xfe\xff` tells us we are having utf-16 (cf. http://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/guess_encoding.html)

Let us try:

```
x = b'\xfe\xff\x000\x008\x00/\x001\x002\x00/\x001\x009\x009\x003'
print(x.decode('utf-16'))
```

which gives

```
'08/12/1993'
```

For completeness:
If the input is given as a string you can use `eval` to turn it into `<class 'bytes'>`:

```
x = eval("b'\\xfe\\xff\\x000\\x008\\x00/\\x001\\x002\\x00/\\x001\\x009\\x009\\x003'")

print(x)   ### b'\xfe\xff\x000\x008\x00/\x001\x002\x00/\x001\x009\x009\x003'

print(x.decode('utf-16'))  ### returns 08/12/1993
```