# How can I get an image's title and subject properties?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to get an image properties - title and subject values and use it for my program. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I can't seem to find a good and simple way to do this. Performance doesn't really matter that much. It will be a small-medium sized project.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697645/how-to-extract-metadata-from-a-image-using-python) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image/4765242) can help you.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like it should do it. I'm going to test it and update this thread.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for some reason, though I made it work with exifread module.