# How to read only image width and height in python, without reading the data?

Tags: python, image, opencv, exif

I want to read only metadata of an image, without reading the data. This should be much faster.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4764932/913098) question, with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18027454/913098) answer, but not sure how to use it.

Also, I prefer a cv2 solution if one exists.

Not looking for:

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread(mypath)
height, width, channels = im.shape
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697645/how-to-extract-metadata-from-a-image-using-python

Comment: thx for the link @AchilleG, I've voted it to be a duplicate.

Comment: there's also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800704/get-image-size-without-loading-image-into-memory which I think is a better fit

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks. The correct answer is actually the 3d one, that was a hard find.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52321252/913098) is the answer