# Call exiftool from Python - basics

Tags: python, exiftool

I would like to call exiftool in Windows 7 from within a python script to both extract and add info to the image tags, but I'm stumbling over the basic workflow to do this.  [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075115/call-exiftool-from-a-python-script) addresses this topic, but I have a couple of basic questions regarding it and am unable to comment on the original question:

1. Where on my system should the executable be stored?
2. What does the *filenames bit do?
3. Can I just specify a list of files in place of *filenames in the 'with ExifTool()' bit, or should I just leave it as is and make sure my directory with my images is my cwd?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. The executable can be stored anywhere on your system - just make sure to pass the path to the ExifTool constructor when you create it:

   with ExifTool('') as e:
       metadata = e.get_metadata(*filenames)
2. `*filenames` is syntax for "exploding" a list (in this example). Rather than passing a single list with filenames to the `self.execute` call, we pass all the filenames as part of the *args.
3. You can specify a list of filenames if you want - `filenames` just needs to be a list of paths for `exiftool` to process.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification...although the script appears to hang.  However, when I use the example posted [here](http://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/) with the appropriate class, it works.

Comment: One more thing: it looks like this class can only extract metadata, but not edit it -- anybody have any experience extending it for editing?