# Changing exif data without re-compressing JPEG image

Tags: python-3.x, image, jpeg, exif

I write a python 3 CLI tool to fix creation dates of photos in a library (see  [here](https://gitlab.com/MaralAfris/ImageSorter/blob/master/tools/library_touch_cli.py).

I use Pillow to load and save the image and piexif to handle exif data retrieval/modification.

The problem I have is that I only want to change the EXIF data in the pictures and not recompress the whole image. It seems that Pillow save can't do that.

My question is:

1. Any better exif library I could use to only play with the exif data (so far I tried py3exiv2, pexif and piexif) ?
2. If not, is there a way to indicate to Pillow to only change the exif of the image without recompressing when saving ?

Thanks !

Here is the code I use to change the creation date so far:

```
# Get original exif data
try:
    exif_dict = piexif.load(obj.path)
except (KeyError, piexif._exceptions.InvalidImageDataError):
    logger.debug('No exif data for {}'.format(obj.path))
    return

# Change creation date in exif_dict
date = obj.decided_stamp.strftime('%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S').encode('ascii')
try:
    exif_dict['Exif'][EXIF_TAKE_TIME_ORIG] = date
except (KeyError, piexif._exceptions.InvalidImageDataError):
    return
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
# Save new exif
im = Image.open(obj.path)
im.save(obj.path, 'jpeg', exif=exif_bytes)
```

Comment: Why not just use `exiftool`?

Comment: Sounds like a nice option. Someone already did this there actually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075115/call-exiftool-from-a-python-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I think that no need to use Pillow.

```
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
piexif.insert(exif_bytes, obj.path)
```

Comment: Yes but wouldn't Pillow recompress the image in order to write the exif data ?
I am using save for now, is insert just touching the exif data ?