# Calling ExifTool from python script hangs in Mac but works in Windows

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, exiftool

I am using the script from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075115/call-exiftool-from-a-python-script/10075210#10075210). I have made one minor modification, which is listed below.

Modification 1

```
sentinel = "{ready}\n"

    def __init__(self, executable="/usr/local/bin/"):
        self.executable = executable

    def __enter__(self):
        app = "exiftool"
        command_line = [app, "stay_open", "True", "-@", "-"]
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(command_line, executable=app, universal_newlines=True,
                                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        return self
```

The rest of the answer posted in the original link is completely unchanged.

I call the above as follows,

```
def main():
    filename = r"/Volumes/backup/2017/MOV_0004.mp4"
    with ExifTool.ExifTool() as e:
        metadata = e.get_metadata(*filename)
    json_str = json.dumps(metadata, indent=2)
    print (json_str)
```

For some odd reason this works absolutely fine on Windows, but I just can't get it to work on a Mac.

In order to get this to work on Windows, I change the one line `sentinel = "{ready}\n"`. I am using python 3.7.1 on the Mac and python 3.6.1 on Windows.

Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: What's the point of using `app = "exiftool"`? Use `self.executable`.

Comment: Try running the following in a Terminal Window to see where your `exiftool` is `type exiftool`

Comment: I use `app="exiftool"` in Windows because without this I get a WinError 5: Access is Denied error. Admittedly, not tried undoing this for the Mac code.

Comment: @insomniac: It should work if you undo that change I would imagine.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, `type exifool` produces this output `exiftool is /usr/local/bin/exiftool`

Comment: @I'L'I, no luck. I changed the code to `self.process = subprocess.Popen(command_line, universal_newlines=True,
                                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` and it still hangs.

Comment: Have you thought about using [PyExiftool](http://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/) instead?

Comment: @StarGeek - thanks for the suggestion. Just did, and it's working.